# Get restaurant reviews from other review sites

Tags: php, review

I am building a restaurant review site using php. I wanted to know how to show reviews from other reviews sites. For example check this [link](http://www.google.com/maps/place?source=uds&q=restaurant&cid=10452532184484608724) to see how google is picking up reviews from other sites. When clicked on, it takes you to their review site.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Without scraping? With an API?

Comment: with an api but if they dont provide api's for getting reviews? google is displaying reviews from various other sites if u checked the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will *probably* find the other sites have partnered with Google for this, however I would be using cURL to get the information you want.

I would suggest you [start here](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/curl-example.htm) with cURL, then have a [look here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/82274-php-curl-get-part-of-page/) to extract the portion you're looking for.

**Edit:** the section of the second link that is relevant is

```
preg_match_all("/<div>.+<\/div>/", $page, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

What this is doing is getting the content you're looking for and then displaying it, you will probably need to define the unique elements with the content you want however, this could mean a separate rule for each website.

I hope this helps for you.

Comment: Thanks Ryan.. The second link does make a lot of sense... Will try it out and see how it works.. Thanks again

Comment: exactly.. i tried the code and it downloaded all the content.. now im going to try and pinpoint what exactly i require.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, make a list of the sites that you want to pull reviews from. Second, read through those sites and see if they have a developer section and if they expose a public API. If they do, look around to see if they have any client libraries for php which you can use to access their API from your php site. If they do have an API but there are no client libraries available, contribute to the community by creating a client library and sharing it as open source. :)

Also, it may be possible that they have an RSS feed of their reviews that you can consume easily of your site, so check that out too.

Comment: P.S. Do this first and don't scrape (in case that's where you were headed). Google will catch you for duplicate content and your SEO will be knocked.

Comment: oh thanks ashelvey.. I tried getting api's from the sites i wanted but we'll have to buy reviews from those sites... what i was thinking was to just put up the reviews and if the site has a problem, then we can remove it from our site or when we have sufficient reviews we can remove it ourselves

Comment: This is a good point that I assume someone looking at this solution would be already aware of. Unfortunately however Google will often knock you on SEO even if you do use APIs and/or RSS because the content is still duplicated and Google cannot tell how the content has been retrieved.

Comment: @Rohit I assume you're aware of the legal liabilities and consequences  you could face with this? It is a dangerous game if you get caught out so do be careful, maybe talk to the sites you want the content from and offer some marketing to them in exchange for temporary free usage of their content or something along these lines. Good luck mate

Comment: @Ryan I will consider talking to them cause i need content only from two sites.. Thanks a lot mate for the possibilities..

Comment: @Rohit no problems mate... happy to help :-)

Comment: @Ryan You're absolutely correct about getting it from API or RSS being as bad. I thought of that right after I posted it. :)

Comment: @ashelevy it's not really bad but it doesn't circumvent the search engine rules on duplicated content. In fact when getting the content via API or RSS it can reduce legal liability because the content owner (generally speaking) is distributing the content.

Answer (score 0):

I think google find News, Blog , Reviews and something like that by site map what web administrators introduce to google as sitemap.xml .
To do this you must get page content what you want to fetch it's reviews ( By CURL or something like that to get remote file ) and fetch reviews by regular expression of HTML